# What Could be Breaking scrollTo?

Tags: javascript

On this page:

http://alien.devprose.com/screenfad

I'm attempting to have it scroll to a specific position using javascript when the page is loaded.  For example purposes I have this code in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.scrollTo(300,300);

</script>
```

However, nothing is happening.  Any ideas?

Comment: *when the page is loaded*....you didn't, you call it immediately in the head.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have jQuery, so the code should be in `$(document).ready()` like so:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() { window.scrollTo(300,300); });
 </script>
```

This way, when the window is done loading it will scroll.

Comment: I do not see this tagged jQuery.

Comment: If you looked at his website, youd see hes using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `window.scrollTo()` until after the document has loaded.  Scripts in the HTML (including both in the head and in the body) are executed before that.  [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load) should explain the best ways to run scripts after it's finished loading.  In summary:

```
window.onload = function() { window.scrollTo(300,300); };
```